# Automatically add a new row filled the given formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to do following thing in Excel:

Say we have two sheets, `Sheet1!A1` I will fill a series of number one by one, I want to `Sheet2 A column` can automatically record the new date in `Sheet1!A1` when it appeared,

e.g, `sheet2` `A column` already has `1,2,3`  in `A1,A2,A3`, when I fill `6` in `Sheet1!A1`, then in `sheet2` it will automatically add a new row `A4` filled with number in `Sheet1!A1` i.e `6`; but if I fill `2` in `Sheet1!A1`, then nothing. The key point is how to automatically add a new row?

Comment: Do you simply mean, that if you enter data in a cell in one sheet, it should be automatically added in another sheet with the same cell address?  `If I fill 2 in Sheet1!A1, then nothing` Pl. explain this.

Comment: not the cell address but the value, if this value has already existed in the record column, then do nothing otherwise extend the record column with new value

Comment: Just a suggestion - Can you not `group` the sheets and add a duplicate filter to columns in sheet `Sheet1!A1`? Grouping would add your data automatically to both sheets and filtering would remove the duplicate ones.